# join operation difference between when distinct is 1 and n?

Tags: sql, join

let say I have a df and df2. 
if I want to join this two tables.

> df : name , classId 
>       df2: classId, time

a) df.classid.distinct().count() = 1 
b) df.classid.distinct().count() = n , n < 500
c) df.classid.distinct().count() = n , n > 100000

if I want to make a join operation. it will be different for this 3 senarios?

Comment: Not at all. You can simply join them on the basis of ClassID. Its Sql engines overhead to look after the join prredicate and giving you the correct result.

Answer (score 0):

A join does not depend on the number of rows in a table. It's always written in the same way. In your case you are looking for:

```
select df.name, df.classid, df2.time
from df 
  join df2 on df.classid = df2.classid;
```